# How to show all trace in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite, compilation

I want to know the trace of the query progressing.
I setting the SQLITE_DEBUG compile option and I give the command such that
"PRAGMA vdbe_debug = true"

However, It only show the trace of vdbe's query processing
I want to know the whole trace, like WALTRACE, 'How to operate Pager and B-Tree Module'

Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WALTRACE macro works differently:

```c
#if defined(SQLITE_TEST) && defined(SQLITE_DEBUG)
SQLITE_PRIVATE int sqlite3WalTrace = 0;
# define WALTRACE(X)  if(sqlite3WalTrace) sqlite3DebugPrintf X
#else
# define WALTRACE(X)
#endif
```

You have to define another symbol, and to manually set the variable.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!
I knew the method to set variable is setting the compile-time option such that SQLITE_TEST or SQLITE_DEBUG, 
I already set theses variables but there is  no trace output.
Can you help me more?

Comment: SQLITE_TEST and SQLITE_DEBUG are *not* variables. The variable is `sqlite3WalTrace`.

Comment: Thank you, I already set the sqlite3WalTrace value to 1 (its original value is 0) but nothing changed.